# How to write unit test for components with vitest in Nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vitest

I'm trying to migrate from Vue 3 to **Nuxt 3**. I've written unit tests for my components using vitest which are *working fine* in my *Vue* app, but the same test in the Nuxt app give me the following error:

> Error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax.
> Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle .vue files.

I've installed `@vitejs/plugin-vue` as a development dependency but nothing happened.

Here is an example of my test files:

```js
import { describe, it, expect } from "vitest";

import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import AtomsButton from "./AtomsButton.vue";

describe("AtomsButton", () => {
  it("button renders properly", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(AtomsButton, { slots: { default: "Button" } });
    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain("Button");
  });
});
```

Here is my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "test:unit": "vitest --environment jsdom"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/test-utils-edge": "^3.0.0-rc.3-27571095.9379606",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.3",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0",
    "jsdom": "^19.0.0",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.3",
    "vitest": "^0.13.1"
  }
}
```

I have no idea what am I doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the [reproduction link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-bhnfe6?file=nuxt.config.ts,app.vue,package.json)

Comment: @tony19 Here is the reproduction link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-bhnfe6?file=nuxt.config.ts,app.vue,package.json

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was struggling with this too and was able to make it work by using a custom Vite config file only for Vitest.

`package.json` file :

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "test:unit": "vitest --config ./vitest.config.js",
    "preview": "nuxt preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^5.1.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.3",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0",
    "jsdom": "^19.0.0",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.4",
    "vitest": "^0.14.2"
  }
}
```

`vitest.config.js` file :

```
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default {
  plugins: [vue()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
  },
}
```

Comment: And how to handle the Nuxt 3 auto imports? Because with this config I need to import all the components or Vue dependencies like ref or reactive.